# Thickbox modal form related

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thickbox

I am using asp.net MVC.

I am opening my login page as Modal page Like this -> [Login demo](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox-3/)

The problem is when user gives incorrect information then I lost parent page.

And this happens because the errors comes with another page and it removes parent page.

So how to update the modal page?

I know ajax update is possible so don't give me that solution.

My strict requirement is show another page In modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Thickbox has an inline mode and iframe mode.

Inline mode, there would be no parent. It just displays content in a `<div>`

IFrame, the html in the iframe would be the child of the document.

So inside the iFrame if you want to refer to javascript in the parent document you must say parent.doSomething();

Comment: If so then can I achieve it in any other way?